# I don't want the navigation to be printed

Tags: printing, html-lists, printing-web-page

Hi I have build an Terms and Conditions sheet. (HTML)
And added an print button. 
this one:

```
document.write("<input type='button' " +
"onClick='window.print()' " +
"class='printbutton' " +
"value='Print'/>");
```

Al good but when I print the page its also wants to print the navigation bar (ul)

How can i prefend that?

Comment: Why do you use document.write() here?

Answer (score 1):

Create a stylesheet for printing only (using a media="print" attribute on the style element), and set display: none on the elements you don't want to have printed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx asjo. 
I will try that.

This is what worked for me.

```
<style type="text/css">

#printable { display: none; }

@media print
{
    #non-printable { display: none; }
    #printable { display: block; }
}
</style>
```

and then this:

```
<div id="non-printable">
    Your normal page contents
</div>

<div id="printable">
    Printer version
</div>
```

Basicly what asjo suggested.